# BOM \ufeff at beginning of org-babel-tangled file

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode, byte-order-mark, org-babel

Recently, I have noticed that `\ufeff` (BOM for UTF-16) is getting prepended to files tangled using `org-babel-tangle`.

- Is my configuration wrong? If yes, which variable have I inadvertantly misconfigured?
- Is this a bug? If not, how do I prevent this from happening?

This causes `\ufeff` to be tangled before my emacs configuration `init.el` files and also before the `#!/usr/bin/env` .

I don't find anything when I grep 'utf-16' in my `user-emacs-home`.

My configuration includes:

```
    (setq locale-coding-system 'utf-8)
    (setq coding-system-for-read 'utf-8)
    (setq coding-system-for-write 'utf-8)
    (setq default-process-coding-system '(utf-8-unix . utf-8-unix))
```

and

```
    (set-terminal-coding-system 'utf-8)
    (set-keyboard-coding-system 'utf-8)
    (set-selection-coding-system 'utf-8)
    (prefer-coding-system 'utf-8)
    (set-default-coding-systems 'utf-8))
```

Comment: I'm using Emacs-29 v29.0.90 compiled from GNU Emacs repository, branch: emacs-29.